# 500GB SSD + 500GB HDD in caddy with bios that detects only 750GB, what would happen?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd, bios

I just got a new 500GB SSD and caddy. I will be installing the SSD as the main disk for my OS and working files and install the HDD within a caddy in place of the optical drive.

I am not exactly sure but I think my bios is capable of 750GB. What would happens in this case especially if the HDD contains data? Could I access all the data?

Comment: Yes and Yes... For a more specific answer you would have to provide additional specific information like model name/numbers of the drives, motherboard/computer, bios revision, etc. In general, relatively modern computer hardware can easily support drives up to 2TB and larger, and the limitation is per drive, not a total, so if you have a 2TB limit and 4 drives connected, assuming everything else is fine you should have 8TB of storage across 4 volumes, so your two 500GB scenario should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIOS limits are per-device. It shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: would I be able to access all data?

Comment: @user10853 - Why wouldn't you be able to access your data?

Comment: I thought the bios might limit what I can access just like RAM. As a confirmation I installed them and can access them